# Как решить ошибку?

Tags: php, xml, ооп, xmpp

Не работает отправка в Jabber, как решить ошибку?
Доброго времени суток, друзья!

Заказчик просит подключить подтверждение аккаунта по Jabber, древний аналог ICQ, но "анонимный"...
И так вот, я нашел [библиотеку](https://github.com/fabiang/xmpp) в GitHub...

Написал на основе её код(версия PHP7)

**самКОД**

```
$token_hash = md5($token);
$address = "tcp://sj.ms:5222";
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$options = new Options($address);
$options->setUsername($username)
->setPassword($password);
$client = new Client($options);
$client->connect();
$message = new Message;
$message->setMessage("Ваш токен на сайте: $token_hash")
->setTo($jabber);
$client->send($message);
```

А сайт возвращает ошибку:
**XML parsing error: "Not well-formed (invalid token)" at Line 1 at column 1**

Ошибка начинается с данной строчки:
**$client->connect();**

*P.S. Гуглил, ничего не нашёл, пытался менять порядок данных в options...*

Comment: Какой сервер Jabber используете?

Comment: @tutankhamun, sj.ms

Comment: Не знал об этом сервисе. Думал вы домен в качестве примера привели

Comment: @tutankhamun, у вас код работает? И какой сервер посоветуете тогда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот попробуй этот: xmpp.jp
Вот тебе сайт чтобы выбрать:
[http://jabberworld.info/Список_работающих_публичных_серверов_Jabber](http://jabberworld.info/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_Jabber)